# Index data.frame by integer(0) for substitution, but avoid the warning

Tags: r, indexing

```
# Here is a data.frame: 
x = data.frame(cbind(1:5, 1:5))
# Here is `integer(0)`
k = integer(0)
k
# For example, you could end up with integer(0) like this:
k = which(is.na(x[,1]))
k
# Now, substituting values in x by k (a null operation in this case) throws 
# a warning:
x[k,1] = 5

Warning message:
In max(i) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I can avoid the warning, either by putting a check before `x[k,1] = 5` to skip the operation if `k = integer(0)`, or by recasting `x` as a matrix instead of a data.frame.  Is there a more graceful way to avoid the warning?

(In addition, what is the point of that warning?)

Comment: I am not getting the warning message.  I use `R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)` in linux

Comment: Argh, I'm getting tired of being a special case, this is the second time in a row that my error/warning is not reproducible:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268430/xlim-not-working-in-plot-gam-in-mgcv

Comment: I'm using R version 3.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: Somebody using windows will check that..

Comment: No warning with R 3.1.1 on win7 either, but I can reproduce it with 3.0.1. Update R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the current R version, but I can reproduce with 3.0.1.

The most graceful way to suppress warnings is `suppressWarnings`:

```
suppressWarnings({x[k,1] = 5})
```

However, this suppresses all warnings the expression could throw, so it might be dangerous (depending on the expression) and a (more specific) `if` condition might be preferable.